# How can I take a few equations as user input?

Tags: c

I've got an assignment that ask me to take a few equations (1-3) from user input as ax+by+cz=d and calculate the determinant and find the matrix and B vector.I have already defined the number of equations between 1 to 3, but I can't figure out how can I get the a,b,c from the input and get it into a matrix? and how can I get that kind of input from user? [the output should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D35xV.png)

Comment: Please try to show some effort in how you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, it's my first time asking here.

Comment: That's no problem - welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines on asking good quality questions. In general it's good to see what sort of specific inputs and outputs you are looking for, and what progress you've already made towards solving the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to define a pointer, because I think this is the best way to go, but i'm new in c programming and i'm having troubles in figuring it out. and still, with a pointer i'm not sure how I should separate the a*x to give me only the a variable.

Comment: To create a pointer, just declare a variable with an asterisk `*` after the type name. Remember to allocate the memory.

Comment: looks like people are throwing good ideas together, but please note, you basically asked how to make a scientific calculator, and extended your question at each attempt to answer. it may be time to accept the help you have been given, and tidy up your question so it is clearer what you have learned. then it may attract upvotes and you can ask other questions.

Comment: i'm aware of that, I wasn't sure what I should do, first time here. that's way I edited my question every time someone asked me something that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note that this is not the code, just a brief idea on how to implement it in C.**

Your approach should be as below:

1) Ask the user for number of equations.

```
scanf("%d", &no_of_equations);
```

2) Ask the user to input equation variables:

```
char var[no_of_equations];
for (i = 0; i < no_of_equations; ++i)
    scanf("%c", &var[i])
```

3) Allocate a 2d array (matrix) using malloc (with number of coefficients same as the number of equations)

```
int *arr[no_of_equations]; 
for (i=0; i<no_of_equations; i++) 
     arr[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
```

4) Take the equations as input and use string manipulation:

```
char* equations[no_of_equations];

for (i=0; i<no_of_equations; i++) 
    equations[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    for (j = 0; equations[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < no_of_equations; k++) {

        if (equations[i][j] == var[k]) {
            arr[i][k] = equations[i][j-1]; // Storing coefficient corresponding to kth coefficient for ith equation
    }
```

The algorithm will take O(n^3). Any improvements are welcome.

Comment: thank you! but can I get a complete equation only by definition as char? would it be possible to get the multiplication and addition between the variables? sorry for the silly question, i'm not so sure about this specific subject.

Comment: Sharon, in the above code, you will need to input equations using gets(), fgets() or scanf() functions, a detailed explanation of which can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/

Comment: great, so I will use string as well. thank you very much

Comment: You're most welcome, wish you all the best for your assignment submission :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the scanf function to get the input from users. With scanf you can specify the type of input you expect. I suggest you to make something like this

```
int i=0,n;
float matrix[3][4];
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("Type the %dth equation: ",i+1);
    n=scanf("%fx+%fy+%fz=%d",&matrix[i][0],&matrix[i][1],&matrix[i][2],&matrix[i][3]);
    if(n<0){
        printf("Error while reading the equations!\n");
        break;
    }

    //put your code to calculate the result here 
}
```

Comment: ...and check the return value of scanf!

Comment: that's great, thanks! but is there any way to help me with the output? I need the matrix to be with .3 numbers. should I define it as a float instead of int?

Comment: I've changed the type of the input to float. If you want to show only 3 decimals on output you can write printf("%.3f",value); when printing a float value

Comment: If the answer is working you can set it as the correct answer

Comment: There's no explanation as to what it does.